# What does C expression ((void(*)(void))0)(); mean?

Tags: c

`((void(*)(void))0)();`

So we have integer 0 type casting to this tricky type `(void(*))(void)` and then executing it. Source claims that this should work, but what does it actually?

This must be one of those C jokes like `#define TRUE FALSE`, I suppose.

Comment: Casting the null pointer to a function pointer, and then calling it.  Doesn't sound like something that should work.

Comment: Which source claims that this should work? Do you have a link? It might be easier to understand in context.

Comment: It is casting to a function pointer.  Looks like a segfault waiting to happen to me.

Comment: Non-standard `abort()`, maybe? ;)

Comment: *Jekyll*'s answer inspires me to ask you whether your question arose in the context of embedded systems?

Comment: This was mentioned in context of a joke: 

`if(cmd == RESET) // if command is RESET`
`((void (*)(void))address)(); // something from black magic`

Comment: @user2984878 that is exactly what I was talking about. I guess that was kernel BSP (maybe Marvell)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is a function expecting no arguments and returning no value:

```
void f(void)
```

This is a pointer to a function expecting no arguments and returning no value:

```
void (*p)(void)
```

This is the *type* of that pointer:

```
void (*)(void) /* just remove the p! */
```

This is that type in parentheses:

```
(void (*)(void))
```

This is a cast to that type (the type in parentheses, followed by a value):

```
(void (*)(void))0
```

Still with me? so far we have the integer value 0 cast to a pointer-to-function-that-takes-no-arguments-and-returns-nothing.

The cast is an expression with pointer-to-function type. When you have one of those you can call it like this:

```
(your expression here)(arguments to the function)
```

The first set of parentheses are just for precedence, and sometimes might not be needed (but this time they are). The end result:

```
((void (*)(void))0)(/* no args */);
```

Takes the value 0, casts it to pointer-to-function-expecting-no-arguments-and-returning-nothing, and calls it, supply no arguments.

Comment: You could also add: 0 is the address where the function(taking no arguments and returning void) resides.

Comment: Take this for some more infos about function pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work#840504

Answer (score 17):

The syntax to cast address to a function pointer and then call it
would look like this:

```
((void (*)(void))address)();
```

It might be clearer to do something like this though:

```
void (*fptr)(void) = (void (*)(void))address;
fptr();
```

Said that `((void(*)(void))0)();`  instruction is used to jump to 0 in firmwares usually. It is a bit improper because it actually calls in 0 instead of jumping to 0, but practically it won't make any difference (a fw hot reboot will be performed)

Comment: What does "*fw*" mean, please?

Comment: firmware, there is the boot address is usually in 0 (or 0xFFFF0000 for arm or i386), this jump (call) will cause the processor hot restart. If you want more information look for ***jump to reset vector***

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I will look for it, in the meantime you can see a small variant in Arduino at http://learn.adafruit.com/system/assets/assets/000/010/293/original/ATmegaBOOT_168.c  Note that this reset is not very suitable for big controllers (like ARM11 or more recent) in which usually it is fired an internal watchdog in order to achieve a more "secure" HW reset.

Answer (score 10):

This treats `NULL` as a function pointer and executes it, it should raise a sigbus or similar on most systems.

```
void(*)(void)   <- type, function pointer taking no arguments and returning no value
(void(*)(void)) <- cast to above type
((...)0)        <- cast NULL/0 to said type
((...)0)()      <- execute the cast value as a function
```

Answer (score 3):

On some embedded system (AVR microcontroller, for example) this might be a way to implement a jump (a call, really) to the reset vector.

You could restart the SW this way, especially if you have disabled interrupts before this.

Answer (score 3):

The AVR's will normally load the user application program at address 0. A bootloader program which is loaded at a much higher address, might jump to (call the function at) address 0. So, the cast and call to the 0 address is a useful construct in this environment.