# what does this statement represent [func ptr]

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I came across a strange function pointer,

```
void * (*f1(void(*f2)(void)))(int ) ;
```

What does the `f1` represent here ?

Comment: Syntax error I guess.

Comment: This explains it very well in [ another question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357106/what-does-c-expression-voidvoid0-mean/20357286#20357286

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
T (*f(U))(V)
```

declares `f` as a function which takes a `U` and returns a pointer to a function from `V` to `T` (i.e. a `T (*)(V)`).

So `f1` is a function that takes a `void (*)(void)` and returns a `void* (*)(int)`.

Naming the types makes it more readable:

```
typedef void (*parameter)();
typedef void* (*result)(int);
result f1(parameter f2);
```

(The name "f2" serves no purpose except for helping the human reading the code interpret it.)

Comment: @Prakash You can think of it that way, but it's not valid syntax. Naming the types using typedefs helps.